# wav file generated from NumPy not audible

Tags: python, audio, numpy, scipy, wav

I have a NumPy array that represents audio data (`dtype` is `np.int16`, me saying "one, two"):

[image: audio data]

Sampling rate is 100Hz. I saved this array into a wav file. However, the wav file is not audible from iTunes, VLC or Audacity. It's just silence. How I saved the array:

```
scipy.io.wavfile.write('output.wav',100,waveform) # 'waveform' is the numpy array
```

Is the sampling rate or amplitude too low? I normalized to -32767 to 32767 but still no sound. How the file looks in Audacity:

[image]

Comment: 100hz? That'd mean your Nyquist frequency is 50hz. Unless you're Barry White or James Earl Jones, you voice probably doesn't down far enough for that.

Comment: 100Hz? Tooooo low. You only get 0-50Hz audio from that. Increase it to 8000Hz to get "phone quality" and 22100Hz for speech, and 44100 for "cd quality".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a sampling frequency of 100Hz the highest audible frequency you get is 50Hz.

The range of human hearing is from about 20 to about 20000Hz.

For "telephone quality" you need 8000Hz and for "cd quality" you need 44100Hz (that is the standard sampling frequency for consumer audio).